# How get entries between numbers with help SQL-Alchemy

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

**I tried to get as**

```
posts_q = Post_Data.query.filter(Count_Data.number.between(26000, 52000)).all()
```

**returns all (## 1,2,3,4) posts, but**

```
posts_q = Post_Data.query.filter(Count_Data.number.between(26000, 33000)).all()
```

**no entries
Why?**

models.py

```
class Post_Data(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'post_data'
  # ...
  terms_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('count_data.id'))

class Count_Data(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'count_data'
  # ...
  number = db.Column(db.Integer)
  posts = db.relationship('Post_Data', backref='counts', lazy='dynamic')
```

sql

```
#1 Count_Data.number = 8000
#2 Count_Data.number = 23000
#3 Count_Data.number = 46000
#4 Count_Data.number = 78000
```

Comment: Because you don't have Amy number between `26000, 33000`

Comment: @metmirr,  thanks, I know! Question is why in the first case, it returns all records?

Answer (score 3):

**I found a solution**, it was necessary to use [`.join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join):

```
Post_Data.query.join(Count_Data).filter(Count_Data.number.between(26000, 52000)).all()
```

returns #3 entry

for consistent comparisons don't need to call [`.join()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join)

```
q = Post_Data.query
q = q.join(Count_Data).filter(Count_Data.number >= 26000)
q = q.filter(Count_Data.number <= 52000)
q = q.all()
```